# apply a user defined function, pass kwarg where the values exist across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Please forgive me if this has been answered, I couldn't find anything that quite fit the need I have here.

I have a dataframe with a mix of float and string fields. It looks something like -

```
data = {'df_to_look_at':['A','B'], 'data_to_use':[100,200]}
```

I have a function that uses the first column to pick a dataframe and the second column to find a value to return. I want to make a new column with the returned value.

My function is something like -

```
def find_value(col_a, col_b):
    
    #set lookup table based on argument
    if col_a == 'A':
        table = table_a
    elif col_a == 'B':
        table = table_b

    #Find the value based on column b, set it to the adj variable, and return the adj variable
    adj = table.loc[(table['Term']==B), 'Adj'].values
```

The line I want to run to make a new columns looks something like this

```
df['new_val'] = df.apply(find_value, col_a = df['df_to_look_at'], col_b = df['data_to_use'])
```

In my real code I have about 5 arguments in my function, one used to set a dataframe to look at, the others are criteria to look up the value needed for the new column. So far I have learned how to pass kwargs into an apply function, but only as absolute values like 3 or 'A', not "the value in this row in column X"

First question asked, I hope I got the point across

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach.  Apply sends columns or rows to the function you define.  So the following would be another way to solve your problem (and probably a faster way).

```
def find_value(row):

    #set lookup table based on argument
    if row['df_to_look_at'] == 'A':
        table = table_a
    elif row['data_to_use'] == 'B':
        table = table_b

    adj = table.loc[(table['Term']==B), 'Adj'].values


#apply across rows
df.apply(find_value, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've seen this solution before (passing a the whole series as the argument and using axis = 1) but I didn't understand it, now it just clicked and I understand why this works and how to apply it!